# Transpiling ES6 to ES5 via gulp.js

Tags: ecmascript-6, gulp, bootstrap-4

As far as i understand, Bootstrap JavaScript sources are written in EcmaScript 6 as they use imports (ES6 feature) like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

I also want use imports in my own projects, to organize JavaScript bundling.

How does Bootstrap transpile the source code to EcmaScript 5 and can i do it the same way via my preferred task running tool gulp.js?

Comment: Check out babel